# Why aren't there $+\infty^{+\infty}$ real numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I was reading this [pop math piece](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-different-sizes-of-infinity-2013-11) on "the different sizes of Infinity." The article explains why the real numbers are uncountably infinite.

Taking a real number, my uneducated mathematical mind intuits that it could be considered as an infinitely-long word made up of letters drawn from an infinitely long alphabet (the rational numbers) in arbitrary combination (hence  $+\infty$ to the power of $+\infty$ possible combinations). This would seem to suggest that the real numbers are countably infinite.

Of course, I know my reasoning must be wrong, but I do not have the mathematical background to find out why. Does anyone care to explain?

Comment: You're looking for the _Cantor diagonalization argument_. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument

Comment: All real numbers can be defined by infinite strings made from a *finite* alphabet. There are only $10$ digits but every real can be made from a string of them.

Comment: In other words, you are asking us why $\aleph^\aleph>\aleph$

Comment: @Lucian I think I am asking why |N^N| does not equal |R|.

Comment: @louism $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the same size as $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But it does. $|\mathbb R|=2^\aleph$

Comment: Therefore, why is R uncountably infinite if the number of elements it contains can be expressed in terms of countably finite sets?

Comment: @louism The elements can be expressed as countably infinite sets. This is not in contradiction with the fact that there are uncountably many of them in total.

Comment: I think I see your point (sort of). I believe I am misguided in thinking that the collection of all sets is a set.

Comment: Aside: the mathematical object usually denoted by $+\infty$ has nothing to do with the notion of size you are asking about. (and also, for this object, $(+\infty)^{+\infty} = +\infty$)

Comment: This may be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380200/can-be-this-handwaving-idea-about-counting-reals-somehow-put-on-solid-ground

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diagonal argument says that $\aleph_0<2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ because
$$2^{\aleph_0}\le\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\le(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$$

Comment: I understand this is correct symbolically, but I fail to rationalize to myself "why" this should be.

Comment: @louism I don't know where's the problem. Cantor's argument shows the infinite sequences on 2 letters are uncountable, so surely the infinite sequences of infinitely many letters are. And my argument shows that you can reduce the infinite sequences on infinitely many letters to the infinite sequences on 2 letters.

Comment: Ah-ha! Now I get it. Thanks for the re-statement / further explanations.

Comment: While this is a convincing argument for someone who has been introduced to cardinals, I fear that this doesn't make any sense to someone without a mathematical background and it appears to me that user2345215 might be convinced by "authority" rather than the given argument.